# An algorithm in PHP to select a subset of the first exactly N elements that add up to X threshold

Tags: php, algorithm, time-complexity

This is the input:

```
$deals = array(
  array('deal' => '1', 'deal_date' => '2017-02-13', 'amount' => '400'),
  array('deal' => '2', 'deal_date' => '2017-04-17', 'amount' => '8900'),
  array('deal' => '3', 'deal_date' => '2017-04-23', 'amount' => '1000'),
  array('deal' => '4', 'deal_date' => '2017-06-02', 'amount' => '2400'),
  array('deal' => '5', 'deal_date' => '2017-07-05', 'amount' => '10500'),
);
```

I am searching for a subset of exactly N elements where the sum of the 'amount' properties is greater then or equal to X and the elements have the lowest 'deal_date' property possible.

If there is no subset that fits the rules:

```
$subset = false;
```

So for N=2 and X=10000, I get this output:

```
$subset = array(
  array('deal' => '2', 'deal_date' => '2017-04-17', 'amount' => '8900'),
  array('deal' => '4', 'deal_date' => '2017-06-02', 'amount' => '2400'),
);
```

for N=3 and X=12000:

```
$subset = array(
  array('deal' => '2', 'deal_date' => '2017-04-17', 'amount' => '8900'),
  array('deal' => '3', 'deal_date' => '2017-04-23', 'amount' => '1000'),
  array('deal' => '4', 'deal_date' => '2017-06-02', 'amount' => '2400'),
);
```

My current idea entails creating an array that contains arrays of the list of deals in every conceivable order.  Then I scan through those for my list of deals that fit the criteria but then I have a list of deals and I am unsure how to determine the 'earliest'.

I'm also looking for the algorithm with the lowest time complexity.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: so, do you need algorithm for 3 or for N?

Comment: Why isn't it deal #1 ($2400) & Deal #2 ($8400)?  Why is it #2 and #4?

Comment: cale_b, mostly because I am stupid and I didnt see I left that value there.  I will change it so the text works, thanks

Comment: Ilya, I need an algorithm for N

Comment: Show your attempts and see if someone can improve upon them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple but roughly this
There will be a better way.

The approximate source is

```
$calculate = 0;
$end_case = array();
$sum = 10000;

// first amount 10000 over value array remove
foreach($deals as $key => $val){
  if($val['amount']>=$sum)unset($deals[$key]);
}

// second Obtaining data
foreach($deals as $key => $val){

  foreach($deals as $k => $v){

    // same deal excetpion
    if($val['deal']==$v['deal']) continue;

    $calc = deal_sum($val['amount'],$v['amount']);
    if($calc>=$sum){
      echo "#".$v['deal']." => ".$val['amount']."+".$v['amount']." = ".$calc."\n";
      array_push($end_case,$v['deal']);
    }

print_r($end_case);
  }
}

function deal_sum($source,$destination){
  $result = $source+$destination;
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: yes! $deals that is top on example output ->  #4 => 8900+2400 = 11300
#2 => 2400+8900 = 11300

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of your algorithm, otherwise large input sets will take forever.

### Algorithm for N:

Returns array() of the first $number_of_deals_to_combine deals from
$deals ordered by 'deal_date', that have at least $threshold or
greater combined amounts or false if no such combination is found.

Uses a rolling window of $number_of_deals_to_combine elements
excluding deals that have too small 'amount'.

```
function combine_deals($deals, $threshold, $number_of_deals_to_combine){
  $return = false;
  //are there enough deals to combine?
  if(count($deals) >= $number_of_deals_to_combine){
    //are deals sorted by date? sort them
    usort($deals,function($a, $b){return strnatcmp($a['deal_date'],$b['deal_date']);});
    //find out if there is a possible solution, by adding up the biggest deals
    $amounts = array_map('intval',array_column($deals,'amount'));
    rsort($amounts); //sort descending
    if(array_sum(array_slice($amounts, 0, $number_of_deals_to_combine)) >= $threshold){
      //find the smallest possible number that is part of a solution
      $min_limit = $threshold - array_sum(array_slice($amounts, 0, $number_of_deals_to_combine - 1));
      //rolling window
      $combined = array();
      foreach($deals as $deal){
        if(intval($deal['amount']) < $min_limit){continue;} //this deal is not part of any solution
        $combined[] = $deal;
        //keep the number of deals constant
        if(count($combined) > $number_of_deals_to_combine){
          $combined = array_slice($combined, count($combined) - $number_of_deals_to_combine);
        }
        //there are enough deals to test
        if(count($combined) == $number_of_deals_to_combine){
          $amount = array_sum(array_map('intval',array_column($combined, 'amount')));
          if($amount >= $threshold){
            $return = $combined;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $return;
}

$threshold = 10000;
$number_of_deals_to_combine = 2;

$result = combine_deals($deals, $threshold, $number_of_deals_to_combine);
```

Are the amount fields always integers? If not, replace all intval with floatval everywhere.